# running my spring boot project without the need for mysql database application when it is run with docker when it is pulled by someone else

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

Since my project is wanted to be used by anyone, I want it to be run with docker without the need to apply a mysql database on the person's computer or without any settings, but I could not do it, I need some help

`.env` file:

```ini
MYSQLDB_USER=root
MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=12345
MYSQLDB_DATABASE=familybudgetapp
MYSQLDB_LOCAL_PORT=3307
MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT=3306

SPRING_LOCAL_PORT=8081
SPRING_DOCKER_PORT=8081
```

`Dockerfile`:

```bash
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim
EXPOSE 8081
ARG JAR_FILE=target/family-budget-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ADD ${JAR_FILE} family-budget-app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","family-budget-app.jar"]
```

`docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=$MYSQLDB_DATABASE
    ports:
      - ${MYSQLDB_LOCAL_PORT}:${MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT}
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql

  web_app:
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerFile
    restart: on-failure
    env_file: ./.env
    ports:
      - ${SPRING_LOCAL_PORT}:${SPRING_DOCKER_PORT}
    environment:
      SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{
            "spring.datasource.url"  : "jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:$MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT/$MYSQLDB_DATABASE?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false",
            "spring.datasource.username" : "$MYSQLDB_USER",
            "spring.datasource.password" : "$MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD",
            "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect" : "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect",
            "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" : "update"
          }'
    volumes:
      - .m2:/root/.m2
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

volumes:
  db:
```

Honestly, I couldn't figure out how to make a change.
I want the project to run by running these commands in the terminal:

```
./mvnw clean package && docker-compose build && docker-compose up
```

without needing db setup directly.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your code? Is something not working? Do you get an error?

Comment: I get this error when I stop mysql database .                                                                                                                                                        

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure.

 So what I want is the user who pulled the project, I want the mysql database to run with docker without needing it on his computer. @g00glen00b